# Determining the format of difference between 2 timestamps in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to subtract 2 timestamp fields to give my hold out the table is in relation to the present time. I am comparing **NOW()** to the **UPDATE_TIME** field **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** database in MySQL.

The problem I have is I wanted to display the difference in terms of hours, months, days, years. Since the timestampdiff function only allows me to specify one UNIT for the result I was wondering if there was a way to do what I am looking for?

I want the result to appear as 45 mins, (then up to hours only) 3 hours old, then 1 day 3 hours olds, and so on until I get to like 4 months, 5 days (again dropping the hours and eventually dropping the days).

Just wondering what the best way to accomodate this would be?
My SQL query so far is below.

Thanks in advance...

```
SELECT 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.UPDATE_TIME,NOW()) 
FROM 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: Even if you find a way to do thtt it will be too complicated. Better use a script/programming language to achieve that.

Comment: This is a nice task to be encapsulated into a user function.

Comment: You can do this using CASE WHEN, e.g. CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.UPDATE_TIME,NOW()) <= 3*3600 THEN '3h' ... AS last_updated